# Поменять текст кнопки из функции

Tags: python

Сижу, делаю крестики нолики, и тут  возникла проблема - надо менять текст кнопок из других функций, поменять не смог, ибо проверка на наличие текста выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Чебупелька/Desktop/Python/tictactoe.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    c11 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c11l(), width=20, height=10)
  File "C:/Users/Чебупелька/Desktop/Python/tictactoe.py", line 74, in c11l
    if c11['text'] == '':
NameError: global name 'c11' is not defined
```

Код ниже, помогите чем сможете.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

i = 0
def start():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x600")
    c00 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c00l(), width=20, height=10)
    c00.grid(row=0, column=0)
    c01 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c01l(), width=20, height=10)
    c01.grid(row=0, column=1)
    c02 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c02l(), width=20, height=10)
    c02.grid(row=0, column=2)
    c10 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c10l(), width=20, height=10)
    c10.grid(row=1, column=0)
    c11 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c11l(), width=20, height=10)
    c11.grid(row=1, column=1)
    c12 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c12l(), width=20, height=10)
    c12.grid(row=1, column=2)
    c20 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c20l(), width=20, height=10)
    c20.grid(row=2, column=0)
    c21 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c21l(), width=20, height=10)
    c21.grid(row=2, column=1)
    c22 = Button(root, text="", command=lambda: c22l(), width=20, height=10)
    c22.grid(row=2, column=2)

def rst():
    root.destroy()

dstr = Button(root, text="Exit", command=lambda: rst(), width=5, height=5)
dstr.grid(row=3, column=0)
root.mainloop()


def c00l():
    global i, c00
    if c00['text'] == '':
        c00['text'] = 'X'
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="ALARM!!!", message="ENGAGED!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Что то типа такого:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("600x600")
        self.__create_buttons()
        self.__add_button_exit()

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def exit(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def __create_functions_for_buntton(self, row, column):
        def click():
            if self.buttons[(row, column)]['text'] == '':
                self.buttons[(row, column)]['text'] = 'X'
            else:
                tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="ALARM!!!", message="ENGAGED!") 
        return click

    def __add_button_exit(self):
        self.button_exit = Button(self.root, text="Exit", command=self.exit, width=5, height=5)
        self.button_exit.grid(row=3, column=0)

    def __create_buttons(self):
        self.buttons = {}
        for row in range(3):
            for column in range(3):
                self.buttons[(row, column)] = Tk.Button(self.root, text='', 
                                                            command=self.__create_functions_for_buntton(row, column),
                                                            width=20, height=10)
                self.buttons[(row, column)].grid(row=row, column=column)

#Using
tictactoe = TicTacToe()
tictactoe.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

сделай `c11` (и все остальные) глобальной либо передай её в твою функцию